Problem with PixelData when writing 3D numpy array to DICOM
I want to write a grayscale 3D pixel array to DICOM, but I have no previous experience with this daunting file format.
Minimum reproducible example:
I've used pydicom and get error that I think is related to the PixelData attribute. But I don't understand how to fix  it. Thankful for all help.
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from pydicom.dataset import FileDataset, FileMetaDataset
import pydicom._storage_sopclass_uids

dir_dcm = os.getcwd()
im_stack =  np.random.randint(0, (2**16)-1, size=(8406, 900, 900), dtype='uint16')
max_val = np.max(im_stack, axis=(0, 1, 2))
bts_stored =  int(math.log(max_val, 2))
max_val_hex = hex(max_val)
min_val_hex = hex(0)
dt = dt.datetime.now()
  
file_meta = FileMetaDataset()
file_meta.ImplementationClassUID = '1.2.3.4'
file_meta.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID = pydicom.uid.generate_uid()
file_meta.MediaStorageSOPClassUID = pydicom._storage_sopclass_uids.CTImageStorage
file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = pydicom.uid.ExplicitVRBigEndian
  
pydicom.dataset.validate_file_meta(file_meta, enforce_standard=True)

path_dcm = dir_dcm + '.dcm'

mf_ds = FileDataset(path_dcm, {}, file_meta=file_meta)
mf_ds.SOPClassUID = '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.14.1'
mf_ds.PatientName = "name^surname"
mf_ds.PatientID = "00-000-000"
mf_ds.ContentDate = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
mf_ds.ContentTime = dt.strftime('%H%M%S.%f')
mf_ds.is_little_endian = True
mf_ds.is_implicit_VR = False
mf_ds.SpecificCharacterSet = 'ISO_IR 100'
mf_ds.SpacingBetweenSlices = r"0.5" 
mf_ds.PixelSpacing = r"0.5\0.5"
mf_ds.ImageOrientationPatient = r"1\0\0\0\1\0"
mf_ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "MONOCHROME2"
mf_ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
mf_ds.PlanarConfiguration = 0
mf_ds.SmallestImagePixelValue = str.encode(min_val_hex)  # zero
mf_ds.LargestImagePixelValue = str.encode(max_val_hex)

mf_ds.TotalPixelMatrixRows = im_stack.shape[2]
mf_ds.TotalPixelMatrixColumns = im_stack.shape[1]
mf_ds.Rows = im_stack.shape[2]
mf_ds.Columns = im_stack.shape[1]
mf_ds.NumberOfFrames = im_stack.shape[0]

mf_ds.SamplesPerPixel = 1
mf_ds.BitsAllocated = 16
mf_ds.BitsStored = bts_stored
mf_ds.HighBit = bts_stored-1
mf_ds.PixelRepresentation = 0

mf_ds.PixelData = im_stack.tobytes()

mf_ds.save_as(dir_dcm+'.dcm', write_like_original=False)

Error:

File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
File "c:\users\kahy\skogforsk\ct-tör - general\kod\untitled0.py", line 65, in 
mf_ds.save_as(dir_dcm+'.dcm', write_like_original=False)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 2061, in save_as
pydicom.dcmwrite(filename, self, write_like_original)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 1153, in dcmwrite
_write_dataset(fp, dataset, write_like_original)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 889, in _write_dataset
write_dataset(fp, get_item(dataset, slice(0x00010000, None)))
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 645, in write_dataset
dataset = correct_ambiguous_vr(dataset, fp.is_little_endian)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 242, in correct_ambiguous_vr
correct_ambiguous_vr_element(elem, ds, is_little_endian)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 198, in correct_ambiguous_vr_element
_correct_ambiguous_vr_element(elem, ds, is_little_endian)
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\filewriter.py", line 119, in _correct_ambiguous_vr_element
elem.value = convert_numbers(
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\ct_env2\lib\site-packages\pydicom\values.py", line 389, in convert_numbers
raise BytesLengthException(
BytesLengthException: Expected total bytes to be an even multiple of bytes per value. Instead received b'0x0' with length 3 and struct format 'H' which corresponds to bytes per value of 2.


The following works for me on my machine:
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from pydicom.dataset import FileDataset, FileMetaDataset
import pydicom.uid

dir_dcm = os.getcwd()
im_stack =  np.random.randint(0, (2**16)-1, size=(3, 900, 900), dtype='uint16')
max_val = int(np.max(im_stack, axis=(0, 1, 2)))  # ***
bts_stored =  int(math.log(max_val, 2))

dt = dt.datetime.now()
  
file_meta = FileMetaDataset()
file_meta.ImplementationClassUID = '1.2.3.4'
file_meta.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID = pydicom.uid.generate_uid()
file_meta.MediaStorageSOPClassUID = pydicom.uid.CTImageStorage
file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = pydicom.uid.ImplicitVRLittleEndian  # *** ExplicitVRBigEndian 
  
pydicom.dataset.validate_file_meta(file_meta, enforce_standard=True)

path_dcm = dir_dcm + '.dcm'

mf_ds = FileDataset(path_dcm, {}, file_meta=file_meta)
mf_ds.SOPClassUID = '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.14.1'
mf_ds.PatientName = "name^surname"
mf_ds.PatientID = "00-000-000"
mf_ds.ContentDate = dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
mf_ds.ContentTime = dt.strftime('%H%M%S.%f')
mf_ds.is_little_endian = True
mf_ds.is_implicit_VR = False
mf_ds.SpecificCharacterSet = 'ISO_IR 100'
mf_ds.SpacingBetweenSlices = r"0.5" 
mf_ds.PixelSpacing = r"0.5\0.5"
mf_ds.ImageOrientationPatient = r"1\0\0\0\1\0"
mf_ds.PhotometricInterpretation = "MONOCHROME2"
mf_ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
mf_ds.PlanarConfiguration = 0
mf_ds.SmallestImagePixelValue = 0 # *** zero
mf_ds.LargestImagePixelValue = max_val  # ***

mf_ds.TotalPixelMatrixRows = im_stack.shape[2]
mf_ds.TotalPixelMatrixColumns = im_stack.shape[1]
mf_ds.Rows = im_stack.shape[2]
mf_ds.Columns = im_stack.shape[1]
mf_ds.NumberOfFrames = im_stack.shape[0]

mf_ds.SamplesPerPixel = 1
mf_ds.BitsAllocated = 16
mf_ds.BitsStored = bts_stored
mf_ds.HighBit = bts_stored-1
mf_ds.PixelRepresentation = 0

mf_ds.PixelData = im_stack.tobytes()

mf_ds.save_as(dir_dcm+'.dcm', write_like_original=False)

I've marked most changes with ***.
I'm using the dev version of pydicom (the _storage_sopclass_uids didn't work), and I had to switch to ImplicitLittleEndian else got a message that save_as couldn't change endianness.  If you're on a big endian machine then you shouldn't need that, else would have to look a little further into how to avoid the conversion in that case.
It seems a key thing was to wrap the numpy max with int, else pydicom was trying to convert the numpy scalar.
An optional style note: you can give pydicom just numbers and it will convert.  So, e.g.
mf_ds.PixelSpacing = [0.5, 0.5]  # instead of r"0.5\0.5"
mf_ds.ImageOrientationPatient = [1,0,0,0,1,0]  # instead of r"1\0\0\0\1\0"


See also this explainer for which Python types to use for a given DICOM element's VR.

Thank you so much for your fast reply. Your code works for me when using only 3 slices in im_stack. however, when I use the full 8406 slices (as in my real data) I get an error: With tag (7fe0, 0010) got exception: argument out of range

I seem to be able to write about 2500 slices without error

Yes, I forgot to mention I also changed the number of slices to 3 - the original was causing my VSCode to basically hang, and the number of slices wasn't pertinent to a minimum example.  The 2500900900*2 corresponds to approximately 4 GB, which is the most that can be represented in a 4-byte DICOM length field.
